# Advice on removing multiple sub-queries (which contains a join) by optimizing Linq To SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, optimization

I'm working on adding globalization to my product cataloge and I have made it work. However, I feel that the underlaying SQL query isn't performing as well as it could and I could need some advice on how to change my Linq To SQL query to make it more efficient.

The tables that are used

**Product** contains a unique id for each product. This column is called EntityID

**TextTranslation** contains the globalized text. The columns in this table are CultureID (a string), TextID (a reference to the text), Value (the actuall globalized text).

**Text** contains the mapping between a globalized text and a product. There is also a column which indicates which type of text it is (like name, description and so on)

**TextType** contains the definition (id, name and description) for a text type.

```
var culturedTexts =
  from translation in ctx.TextTranslations
  join text in ctx.Texts on translation.TextId equals text.TextId
  where translation.CultureId == "en-EN"
  select new
  {
    text.EntityId,
    text.TextTypeId,
    translation.Value,
  };

var products =
  from p in ctx.Products
  let texts = culturedTexts.Where(i => i.EntityId == p.EntityId)
  select new Model.Product
  {
    Description = texts.Where(c => c.TextTypeId == (int)TextType.Description).SingleOrDefault().Value,
    Name = texts.Where(c => c.TextTypeId == (int)TextType.Name).SingleOrDefault().Value
  };
```

When this is executed I get a query which looks like

```
SELECT (
    SELECT [t1].[Value]
    FROM [Common].[TextTranslation] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Common].[Text] AS [t2] ON [t1].[TextId] = [t2].[TextId]
    WHERE ([t2].[TextTypeId] = 2) AND ([t2].[EntityId] = [t0].[EntityId]) AND ([t1].[CultureId] = 'sv-SE')
    ) AS [Description], (
    SELECT [t3].[Value]
    FROM [Common].[TextTranslation] AS [t3]
    INNER JOIN [Common].[Text] AS [t4] ON [t3].[TextId] = [t4].[TextId]
    WHERE ([t4].[TextTypeId] = 1) AND ([t4].[EntityId] = [t0].[EntityId]) AND ([t3].[CultureId] = 'sv-SE')
    ) AS [Name]
FROM [Catalog].[Product] AS [t0]
```

So each globalized text (Name, Description) in the LINQ query gets its own sub query and associated join. Is it possible to streamline this a bit and remove each text type getting its own join and subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that they are getting different TextTypeId values, how would you prefer the TSQL to look? If you do a single JOIN, you'll have to put in a messy `SELECT CASE` or similar to discriminate between type "1" and type "2".

One option would be to to simply bring back all the suitable rows and do the final projection in-memory at the client, but to be honest I expect that the SQL optimizer will make light work of that TSQL anyway... especially if that query hits a good spanning index.